# Составить регулярное выражение для вывода групп одинаковых символов

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Задача такая:
Сформируйте новую строку, отличающуюся от исходной тем, что группы идущих подряд одинаковых символов разделены символом *. Пример

```
ееннне -> ее*ннн*е, ппрол-> пп*р*о*л.
```

Есть такое выражение `(.)\1*`. Но оно возвращает следующий результат: `aaabbcddd -> a, b, c, d`. А мне нужно `aaaa, bb, c, ddd`.

Comment: Думаю что надо еще одну группу `((.)\2*)` из за этого поменяется группа захвата одинаковых символов, а полный захват(идентичные символы подряд) будет в группе 1

Comment: Помогло, благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно поменять

```
(.)(?!\1|$)
```

на

```
\1*
```

Для меня оказалось неожиданным, что в lookAhead можно использовать выделенную группу

**[demo](https://regex101.com/r/NK9ll6/1)**

Comment: Спасибо, работает.